# graphqljs - Query root type must be provided

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

How do I get around this error? For this particular schema, I do not need any queries (they're all mutations). I cannot pass `null` and if I pass an empty `GraphQLObjectType` it gives me the error:

```
Type Query must define one or more fields.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/450) (maybe other SDL tools too), you can specify an empty type (such as `Query`) using:

```
type Query
```

Instead of

```
type Query {}
```

If you're building the schema programatically you'll have to add dummy query, much like:

```
new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    _dummy: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
  }
})
```

Which is the programmatic equivalent of the SDL:

```
type Query {
  _dummy: String
}
```

Comment: kind of odd how you need to specify Query even though you don't need it. I'll mark this as answer after I give it another while.

Comment: @A.Lau It's safe to mark this as accepted. If you check the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Root-Operation-Types), it specifically spells out that "[t]he query root operation type must be provided and must be an Object type." Only the mutation and subscription root operation types are optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Node.js express -

Your schema should have both Root query and root Mutation, although you don't have any query resolvers but still you need to define the root query.

E.g. -

```
type RootQuery {
hello: String!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using express you can do this:

```
const {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLString} = require("graphql")

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "Query",
        fields: () => ({
            message: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve: () => "Hello World"
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Use `GraphQLObjectType`. And the property `Query` should be in lowercase as `query`.